# Is my chlorine sample real?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, identification

I bought a pressurized liquid chlorine ampoule online and I was surprised how thick it was.  It was more like oil than water.  Here's a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/p_6-0Nu51kY?t=48) showing someone else with a very similar sample.

I trust my seller but I’m wondering why is it so thick? It doesn’t flow easily.

Comment: The only thing thick is the wall of that ampoule.

Comment: I have no idea how big the ampoule is but be very careful, chlorine gas is very bad for your lungs

Answer (score 3):

At $\pu{20 °C}$ dynamic viscosity of liquid chlorine is about $\pu{0.35 mPa·s}$ (see Figure 4 from [1, p. 7]), whereas [dynamic viscosity of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Selected_substances) is about $\pu{1 mPa·s}$, e.g. water is nearly 3 times more viscous at room temperature than liquid chlorine, which should not appear that thick.

> [image]
>
> **Figure 4.** Viscosities of chlorine gas and liquid.

Note that your perception of viscosity and "thickness" may be distorted due to capillary effect if your chlorine sample is sealed in a tiny ampule.

#### References

1. Chlorine: Principles and Industrial Practice, 1st ed.; Schmittinger, P., Ed.; *Wiley-VCH: Weinheim; New York*, **2000**. ISBN 978-3-527-29851-8.

Comment: Capillary effect can make a fluid appear to be more viscous?